# getting null as a result in callback AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to verify otp using the sendotp npm module, but sendOTP.verify method i'm getting the result of callback as null. How can i verify whether otp has been verified of or not.

sendOTP - https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendotp

```
exports.handler = async (event,context,callback) => {
    const SendOtp = require('sendotp');
    const sendOTP = new SendOtp('260981AZN8sH3O5c551802');
    let mobileNum = event.mobile.toString();
    let otp = event.otp.toString();
    sendOTP.verify(mobileNum, otp, (error, data) => {
        callback(null,{statusCode:200,body:data.type});
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the async keyword?

Comment: Try removing the async keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two lambda function invocation types - synchronous and asynchronous. Synchronous invocation will block the caller which will wait for the response. Asynchronous invocation type will not block the caller and it will return immediately after it has been called with no - `null` -  response.

If you place `async` keyword in front of your function, you are specifying the function to be called asynchronously, therefore the `null` response that you are getting is expected behavior.

If you don't want it to be asynchronous, then change your header to

```
exports.handler = (event,context,callback) =>
```

Note that some services will use their predefined lambda invocation type when invoking lambda function without honoring your choice (i.e when you subscribe lambda function to s3 event, it will always be invoked asynchronously).

Comment: You are confusing handler functions declared with/without `async` ... and synchronous/asynchronous Lambda *invocations*.  Despite the common use of the word "async," these two things are **completely** unrelated. Both coding styles are fully compatible with both invocation types.  The problem here is that an `async` handler function needs to return a promise (or a value that will be implicitly promisifed), and not use `callback`.

Comment: thank you man, i totally forgot about that async keyword. It helped me. :D